# Doctrine ODM how to avoid hydrators automatic generation

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

Doctrine ODM rewrites the hydrators classes everytime I load a page;

This is quite bad - especially in production.

How can I avoid that? Here's my configuration:

```
$config = new Configuration();
                $config->setProxyDir(getcwd().'/models/proxies');
                $config->setProxyNamespace('MyNamespace\Proxies');
                $config->setHydratorDir(getcwd().'/models/hydrators');
                $config->setHydratorNamespace('MyNamespace\Hydrators');
                $config->setDefaultDB(MONGO_DB);
                $config->setMetadataDriverImpl(AnnotationDriver::create(getcwd().'/models/docModels'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at doctrine mongodb-odm source code
You can disable automatic hydrator generation this way:

```
$config->setAutoGenerateHydratorClasses(false);
```

..some references here:
http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/mongodb_odm/1.0/class-Doctrine.ODM.MongoDB.Configuration.html